# Relative position of elements in adic space

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I'm trying to understand a certain function on a specific adic space I'm stuck on something silly and is probably due to my lack of understanding of the points in this case. This is Proposition 3.3.5 of  Scholze's  MSRI lecture notes.

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}_p [[T]]$, and let $Y=Spa(A,A)^{an}$ . Then one can define a unique continuous surjection $\kappa: Y \to [0,\infty]$ given by $\kappa(x)=\frac{\log |T(\tilde x)|}{\log |p(\tilde x)|}$ where $\tilde x$ is the maximal generalization of $x$. Now the fact that confuses me is that $\kappa(x)=0$ if and only if $|p(x)|=0$. I can see what $|p(X)|=0$ implies $\kappa(x)=0$, but why is the converse true? In other words why is $\log |T(\tilde x)| \in [-\infty,0)$ and not in $[-\infty,0]$? Why can I not have $|T(\tilde x)|=1$?.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are taking the $(p,T)$-adic topology on $A$. In this topology the element $T$ is topologically nilpotent, so for any $x \in \mathrm{Spa}(A,A)$ you have $|T(x)|<1$.

Comment: It's very critical that the $\operatorname{spa}$ and $\operatorname{spv}$ functors take *topological rings* as input, and not just rings. There is really 3 pieces of data in $\operatorname{spa}(A,A^+)$

Comment: Of course! Thats what I was missing. Its clear now. Thanks

Comment: @JoeBerner: As a minor correction, Spa is applied to topological rings (with extra data) but Spv is a functor on bare rings (no topology). For example, as you know, ${\rm{Spv}}(A)$ is a spectral space for any commutative ring $A$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that $\operatorname{spa}$ is an overloaded operator. Thank you